# Convert python to c# neural network

Tags: python, opencv

Hy guys.
I'm working with face-emotion recognition program and need to convert this code from python to c#. This is a nueral network with which help we could recognize emotions. The network outputs a list of softmax scores for the seven classes. The emotion with maximum score is displayed.

Here is code:

> Python

```
class EMR:

  def __init__(self):
    self.target_classes = ['angry', 'disgusted', 'fearful', 'happy', 'sad', 'surprised', 'neutral']

  def build_network(self):
      """
      Build the convnet.
      Input is 48x48
      3072 nodes in fully connected layer
      """ 
      print("\n---> Starting Neural Network \n") 
      self.network = input_data(shape = [None, 48, 48, 1])
      print("Input data",self.network.shape[1:])
      self.network = conv_2d(self.network, 64, 5, activation = 'relu')
      print("Conv1",self.network.shape[1:])
      self.network = max_pool_2d(self.network, 3, strides = 2)
      print("Maxpool",self.network.shape[1:])
      self.network = conv_2d(self.network, 64, 5, activation = 'relu')
      print("Conv2",self.network.shape[1:])
      self.network = max_pool_2d(self.network, 3, strides = 2)
      print("Maxpool2",self.network.shape[1:])
      self.network = conv_2d(self.network, 128, 4, activation = 'relu')
      print("Conv3",self.network.shape[1:])
      self.network = dropout(self.network, 0.3)
      print("Dropout",self.network.shape[1:])
      self.network = fully_connected(self.network, 3072, activation = 'relu')
      print("Fully connected",self.network.shape[1:])
      self.network = fully_connected(self.network, len(self.target_classes), activation = 'softmax')
      print("Output",self.network.shape[1:])
      print('\n')
      self.network = regression(self.network,optimizer = 'momentum',metric = 'accuracy',loss = 'categorical_crossentropy')
      self.model = tflearn.DNN(self.network,checkpoint_path = 'model_1_nimish',max_checkpoints = 1,tensorboard_verbose = 2)
      self.load_model()

  def predict(self, image):
    """
    Image is resized to 48x48
    model.predict() is an inbuilt function in tflearn. 
    """
    if image is None:
      return None
    image = image.reshape([-1, 48, 48, 1])
    return self.model.predict(image)

  def load_model(self):
    """
    Loads pre-trained model.
    model.load() is an inbuilt function in tflearn
    """
    if isfile("model_1_nimish.tflearn.meta"):
      self.model.load("model_1_nimish.tflearn")
      print('\n---> Pre-trained model loaded')
    else:
        print("---> Couldn't find model")
```

Comment: This project I found at GitHub https://github.com/atulapra/Emotion-detection

Comment: Alright so you need to convert this python code to C#, where are you stuck ? What's the problem / question ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code conversion service. Please show your efforts

Comment: This code depends on tensorflow. What Deep Learning framework do you intend to use in C#?